# Задание расположение элементов

Tags: java, android, xml

Как их расположение, чтобы два элемента были друг под другом,а не рядом справа?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/rootLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    tools:context="com.hideme.Menu">
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="startGame"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_start"
                android:src="@drawable/button_start"
                android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий вариант:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/rootLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/colorWhite"
              tools:context="com.hideme.Menu" android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:onClick="startGame"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/empty"
            android:src="@drawable/button_start"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: У ImageButton android:layout_width="match_parent"

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй `android:orientation="vertical"` на `android:orientation="horizontal"`.